# composite patterns inside bash case statements

Tags: bash

I cannot get composite patterns as described in http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching to match inside my case statement:

```
i=33; case $i in *([A-Za-z0-9]) ) echo "alphanumeric";; * ) echo "bah";; esac;
```

I would expect the above script to display "alphanumeric" but instead it fails with:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Any idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try turning on the `extglob` shell option like this:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then you can use the extended pattern matching operators:

```
i='33'; case $i in *([A-Za-z0-9]) ) echo "alphanumeric";; * ) echo "bah";; esac;
```

From the man page:

> extglob - If set, the extended pattern matching features described above under Pathname Expansion are enabled.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks ! It was right in front of my eyes from the beginning...