# bash case composite patterns doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm writing a simple bash script to detect the pattern of user input, here is the script:

```
printf "Enter charachter:\n";
read input

case $input in
    +([a-z]) )
        echo "lower case";
        ;;
    [A-Z])
        echo "Upper case";
        ;;
    [0-9])
        echo "Integer";
        ;;
    "")
        echo "Nothing";
        ;;  
    *)
        echo "Bad input";
        ;;
esac
```

I get this error :

```
 line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 line 5: `  +([a-z]) )'
```

I tried the solution suggested here:
[composite patterns inside bash case statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965753/composite-patterns-inside-bash-case-statements)

and still got the same error.

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` works for me. Are you certain you set it in that script? (And that you're running bash?)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use

```
[a-z]
```

instead of

```
+([a-z])
```

?

Or i just didn't get your script purpose?

Comment: It worked when I added `shopt -s extglob` inside the script.. at first I was setting it from terminal before calling the script.

Comment: @OdO : Yes, but you haven't told us why you think you need the extra syntax, i.e. `+(` when testing for a lowercase character, that you're not using for any of the other tests. Using `shopt -s extglob` is really over kill. And using this feature when you don't need it, you won't understand when is the appropriate to use it. SadLugi is right. I would add, keep it simple! Good luck to all.